# Mono created features available on .NET?

Tags: .net, mono, pdc

I noticed the following today: [Mono at the PDC 2008](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-01-1.html)?

> My talk will cover new technologies that we have created as part of Mono. Some of them are reusable on .NET (we try to make our code cross platform) and some other are features that specific to Mono's implementation of the CLI.

Posted by [Miguel de Icaza](http://tirania.org/blog/) on 01 Oct 2008

Does anybody know what type of new technologies he is refering too?

Sounds like a great talk

[**UPDATE**]   [Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC54/)  is the video of Miguel's talk

- [Mono's SIMD Support: Making Mono safe for Gaming](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html)
- [Static Compilation in Mono](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-05.html)
- [Unity on Linux, First Screenshots](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-14.html)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

These are some of the major [libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries) that you can use:

- [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp), the Cross platform GUI API Unix, Windows, MacOS X,

  - this is an entire stack of libraries and includes widgets (with Gtk+), Accessibility and international text rendering (with PangoSharp).
- [Mono.DataConvert](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert) - System.BitConverter implemented correctly, and well designed.
- [Mono.Addins](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Addins) - Extensibility Framework, similar to MEF.
- [Mono.Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo) - Cairo Graphics Binding.
- [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) - ECMA CIL Image Manipulation.
- Xml.Relaxng - [RelaxNG](http://www.relaxng.org/) parsing and validation.
- [Novell.Directory.Ldap](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11204.html) - LDAP libraries.
- [Daap.Sharp](http://github.com/mono/daap-sharp) - An implementation of the DAAP protocol

  - (Music exchange protocol, you can consume or expose music sources)
- [Mono.Upnp](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Upnp) - Universal Plug and Play implementation in managed code.
- [Mono.ZeroConf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf) - Cross platform ZeroConf/Bonjour API for .NET apps.
- [BitSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/Bitsharp) - Bittorrent client/server library, now called [MonoTorrent](http://www.monotorrent.com/)
- [Mono.Nat](http://monotorrent.blogspot.com/2006/12/on-yet-another-new-topic-im-proud-to.html) - Network Address Translation.
- [Mono.Rocks](http://www.mono-project.com/Rocks) - Useful Extension methods/Functional features for C#, now superseded by [Cadenza](http://www.gitorious.org/cadenza)
- SmugMugSharp - Bindings to talk to SmugMug
- [Crimson](http://www.mono-project.com/Crimson) - Crypto libraries beyond what is available in .NET
- [Mono.WebBrowser](http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser) - Wrapper for Firefox or WebKit.
- WebkitSharp - Bindings to use WebKit from C#
- [GtkSharpRibbon](http://debackerl.wordpress.com/2008/08/26/summer-of-code-summary-gtk-sharp-ribbon/) - The Ribbon, implemented in Gtk# (cross platform)
- IPodSharp - Library to communicate and manipulate iPods.
- TagLibSharp - Library to annotate multimedia files (tagging).
- Exiv2Sharp - EXIF reading/writing library.

Linux Specific:

- [Mono.Posix](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=0@N%3AMono.Posix)/[Mono.Unix](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=0@N%3AMono.Posix).
- [NDesk.DBus](http://www.ndesk.org/DBusSharp)
- [Mono.Fuse](http://www.jprl.com/Projects/mono-fuse.html) - User-space file systems.

I am sure I am missing a bunch of other libraries.

Most of these (and many more) are linked to via the [Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries) page.

Comment: Very interesting list.  Mono.ZeroConf is in there twice though.

Comment: This list was so useful I decided to fill in the links that I decided to track down. I avoided linking to just the sources where I could find no serious announce/intro page. Hopefully it doesn't offend

Comment: I didn't know about Mono.Rocks - awesome!

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza : is there any possibility to render web page over Layered window form.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe things like [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) and [Monovation](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-29.html) and the [interactive shell](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl)?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [roadmap](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Project_Roadmap), maybe the new JIT/IL implementation that they're quite proud of; could be the C# Evaluation API / C# Shell. However, I suspect we'll have to wait for PDC to find out...
Many of the roadmap items are (quite reasonably) like-for-like comparable with MS equivalents - but maybe they've sneaked in a few extras on the quiet ;-p

Answer (score 1):

there's also the [C# eval](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-10.html) and [C# scripting shell](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-08.html) that works only on Mono 2.2 at present...

Answer (score 1):

[Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/migueldeicaza) himself has been spotted on stack overflow: maybe you'll get an answer straight from him.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [Mono.Options](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-14.html), a very useful command-line options parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.0) is more details about Mono 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are still targetting 1.1, then Mono.Data is an excellent abstraction similar to what DbProvider does in 2.0 ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) announced will suport Mono in next versions. Maybe will the first thrid-party compnents commercial company support Mono. This is great. [MonoDevelop](http://www.MonoDevelop.com) is now supported in Windows. I seen great future for Mono.